# How do you calculate mergers and acquisitions firepower?

Tags: finance

I think the title is pretty self explanatory but I would really appreciate an answer. I am not sure if I am in the right place nor am I certain I use the tags necessary for the right traction. So any help in that regard would also be appreciated

Comment: One of the calculations people use is the Herfindahl-Hirschman Index.  This is more a market concentration calculation.  Not sure if it addresses your question re: "Firepower"

Comment: In one asset I found the definition to be the following
"Firepower: a company’s capacity to fund transactions based on its balance
sheet. It has four key inputs: cash and equivalents; existing debt; debt capacity,
including credit lines; and market capitalizations."

So is the Herfindahl-Hirschman Index a method of calculating that or is there a specific metthod to calculating firepower and if so how? Is really the question I am now facing

Comment: I think the Herfindahl Hisrchman is useful in merger acquisition work, but I do not think it is is used specifically for "Firepower".

Comment: This is the first time I hear about firepower.

Comment: BJ: For sure I have never heard of quantitative models for Firepower. It seems more like a number that Investment Bankers estimate based partly on experience, judgement, current mkt conditions etc. So I do not think quant.stackexchange is suitable forum for this question.